# Is using BigQuery broadcast joins an optimization over hash joins?

Tags: google-bigquery

I generated a test table this way:

```
CREATE TABLE test.test_join AS
SELECT
  id AS id,
  REPEAT(SHA512(CAST(id AS STRING)), 10) AS payload
FROM
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 1000000)) AS id
```

Then, I try this request by changing the value of XXX:

```
WITH a AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `test.test_join`),
b AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `test.test_join`
  WHERE
    id < XXX)
SELECT
  a.*, b.*
FROM
  a
INNER JOIN
  b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE
  RAND() < 2  # Prevents BigQuery from using cache
```

With XXX = 200000, it looks like it's a value for which for BigQuery will consistently broadcast join to all workers. I can verify this thanks to the "EXECUTION DETAILS" tab ("INNER HASH JOIN EACH  WITH ALL  ON $1 = $10").

With XXX = 225000, it looks like it's a value for which BigQuery will consistently hash join (shuffle) to all workers. "INNER HASH JOIN EACH  WITH EACH  ON $1 = $10" is written in the "EXECUTION DETAILS" tab.

In Google BigQuery: The Definitive Guide, O'Reilly, the authors write "[Hash joins], in general, are much more computationally expensive".

But whether I'm running the query with 200000 or 225000, I don't see much of a difference in the "bytes billed" section of the "JOB INFORMATION" tab (~620 MB).

Moreover, over 30 iterations, the duration of the query looks similar, no matter the type of join (broadcast or hash).

```
% python -m timeit -n 30 -r 1 -s "from test_broadcast import main_broadcast" "main_broadcast()"
30 loops, best of 1: 3.85 sec per loop
% python -m timeit -n 30 -r 1 -s "from test_broadcast import main_hash" "main_hash()"
30 loops, best of 1: 3.89 sec per loop
% cat test_broadcast.py
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

query = """
WITH a AS (SELECT * FROM `test.test_join`),
b AS (SELECT * FROM `test.test_join` WHERE id < 200000)
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE RAND() < 2
"""


query_hash = """
WITH a AS (SELECT * FROM `test.test_join`),
b AS (SELECT * FROM `test.test_join` WHERE id < 225000)
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE RAND() < 2
"""


def main_broadcast():
    job = client.query(query)
    job.result()


def main_hash():
    job = client.query(query_hash)
    job.result()
```

I am aware that in order to optimize BigQuery queries, we should always search for ways to reduce the amount of data that is read and joined.

What I am wondering, though, is if it's useful to look for ways to reduce one part of the join under the ~150 MB threshold that allows BigQuery to perform broadcast joins.

Is my example biased? I'm interested to know for what reason and how I could generate synthetic data in a simple way to highlight a performance improvement either in terms of latency or billing.

Comment: The "bytes billed" is determined by the size of the raw tables quered. It does not increase if data is read several times or shuffled. Broadcast joins are always to better than Hash joins. You found that at about 200000 the join methods are changing. Well, I guess this point is determined by the backend to use the best joing method. Therefore, you should not see much time differences between these methods at that data amount.

Comment: But then does it really make sense to say that "Broadcast joins are always better than Hash joins" ?